# Возможно ли проигнорировать один последний коммит в мастер ветке?

Tags: git, github

Суть проблемы в том, что при работе с напарником через github возникла такая ситуация, что он успел в мастер ветку сделать коммит с изменениями, которые наверняка создадут у меня конфликт слияния моей рабочей ветки в мастер.

Можно ли как-то откатить ситуацию в мастере на один коммит назад, чтоб я мог безболезненно сделать слияние и потом пул-реквест?

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Что бы напарник потом разгребал конфликт?

Comment: @AlexeyTen т.е. все равно кому-то надо будет разрешать конфликт? Если не мне, то ему?

Comment: Ну а как вы хотели? Если у вас несовместимые изменения, то кому-то придётся их делать совместимыми

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, понял. Значит буду сам решать проблему.

Comment: Используйте чаще `git pull --rebase origin master`, и ваши волосы... :)

Comment: @0andriy, а не могли бы вы пояснить, что при этом произойдет? Именно `origin`, а не `upstream`? Я работаю с напарником через "треугольник" если чё, ну, то есть у меня fork его проекта.

Comment: `origin master` просто стандартное, замените на ваши данные. Перед тем как вы собираетесь сделать `git push`, запускаете вышеприведенную команду. Если она обнаружит новые комиты, то ваши будут перенесены на новую базу (`rebase`). Конфликты всё равно придётся разгребать, но зато основная ветка будет чистая.

Comment: @0andriy понятно, спасибо